# Can't apply shader to OBJ

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, shader

Ok so, I've declared a new material shader (a simple normal map) and I'm trying to apply it to an OBJ (a simple cube).
When I try it, Three.js tells me:

```
.WebGLRenderingContext: GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawElements: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 2
```

This is the part of code that loads the OBJ and declares the material shader:

```
// texture
var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
manager.onProgress = function (item, loaded, total) {
    console.log(item, loaded, total);
};

var diffuse = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("diffuse.jpg");
var normal = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("normal.jpg");
var discplacement = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("displacement.jpg");
var specular = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("specular.jpg");


//

var specularColor = 0xcccccc;
var diffuseColor = 0x888888;
var ambiantColor = 0xffffff;

var shader = THREE.ShaderLib["normalmap"];
var uniforms = THREE.UniformsUtils.clone(shader.uniforms);


uniforms["enableAO"].value = true;
uniforms["enableDiffuse"].value = true;
uniforms["enableSpecular"].value = true;
uniforms["enableReflection"].value = true;
uniforms["enableDisplacement"].value = true;
uniforms["uShininess"].value = true;

uniforms["tAO"].texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("AO.jpg");

uniforms["tNormal"].value = normal;
uniforms["uNormalScale"].value.set(1.0, 1.0);

uniforms["tSpecular"].value = normal;

uniforms["tDisplacement"].value = normal;
uniforms["uDisplacementScale"].value = 0;

uniforms["tDiffuse"].value = diffuse;

uniforms["uSpecularColor"].value.setHex(specularColor);
uniforms["uAmbientColor"].value.setHex(ambiantColor);

var parameters = {
    fragmentShader: shader.fragmentShader,
    vertexShader: shader.vertexShader,
    uniforms: shader.uniforms,
    lights: true
};
var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial(parameters);
material.needsUpdate = true;

// If I use this code to load a mesh and apply the material, it works
//var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(120, 120, 120);
//geometry.computeTangents();
//
//var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
//scene.add( mesh );         


// OBJ Model
// If I use this code to load the mesh and apply the material, it doesn't work

var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader(manager);
loader.load('cube.obj', function (object) {

    object.buffersNeedUpdate = true;
    object.uvsNeedUpdate = true;

    object.traverse(function (child) {

        if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {

            child.material = material;
            //child.material.overdraw = true
            //child.material.map = texture;



        }

    });

scene.add(object);

});
```

The result: Three.js gives me the warning and nothing is rendered on the screen.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good day, I suspect the problem lies with the "tAO" uniform. Instead of:

```
uniforms["tAO"].texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("AO.jpg");
```

change `.texture` to `.value`

```
uniforms["tAO"].value = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("AO.jpg");
```

The GL error may be a consequence of the missing texture map. Otherwise the code looks fine. If all else fails, only enable and push the normal and diffuse maps and see where that gets you to start.